# FancyBox (2.1.3) showing partial content in compatibility mode

Tags: jquery, fancybox, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, fancybox-2

I'm trying to embed fancybox onto a CRM2011 form do display a reference page. Problem is the content doesn't seem to fully render when in compatibility mode. Unfortunately I don't have any control over the doctype or html tags (for compliance with MS Dynamics).

I realize this probably doesn't even qualify as a FancyBox issue, but I'm just hoping you folks might have somewhere I can start looking.

Here's the code I'm using to initialize:

```
$.fancybox.open(
{
    href: 'https://myreferralpod.com/refapp/',
    title: 'Create Referral', // + name
    type: 'iframe',
    iframe: {preload: true},
    padding: 5,
    margin: [20,20,5,20],
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            closeClick : false,
            showEarly  : false
        }
    },
    //autoResize : true,
    fitToView : true,
    width : '80%',
    height : '80%',
    openEffect : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    arrows: false
});
```

(Sorry, can't post images yet)

Here's what shows up in compatibility mode:
[Compatibility Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBcVt.png)

Here's what shows up in regular (desired)
[Regular Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwh15.png)

Comment: Why fancybox? Why not simply jQueryUI's dialog method? What do you need from fancybox over and above jQueryUI?

Comment: do you need help posting images? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: What if you create a simple test by embeding your page, e..g, using something like <iframe src="your_document"></firame> - is the page fully rendered or not? If not, then the problem is with the page.

Comment: if this is a browser specific issue, please consider adding that browser tag.

Comment: @gibberish : because fancybox is cool ;)

Comment: @kinjal - I didn't have enough reputation yet to post images and can only add 5 tags

Comment: @Janis - Good call on the iFrame, I'll give that a shot in a minute here.

Comment: @Janis - Putting an iframe directly on the page renders properly, seems like it is something to do with fancybox

Comment: @PauloCristini You will get points for just completing your profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<div class="container" id="page"...` needs to have an additional css style added to it.  Try adding `position:relative`

This is within the `myreferralpod.com/refapp/` page (not on the CRM side).

Comment: Adding this in the IE developer tools makes the content show. I'll have to speak with the website owners to see if this will cause any issues on their end. Can you please explain what's going on here to make it work? I don't delve into this area often and so I don't know much about it.

Comment: IE6/7 had a weird bug with positioning.  When you go compatibility mode it throws in some of these odd bugs.